# How to Pass URL to iFrame in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have no experience with Vue or JS.

I want to pass a YouTube link from data() to iFrame.

Can this be done?

If so what steps are necessary to do so?

The code below shows what I have so far, though I'm not even sure if it's correct, as this is my first time in Vue.js and JS world.

I have looked here and elsewhere for ideas on how to do this but have not yet found anything I can use.

Any helpful tips are greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
<template>
   
    <div>
           
          <iframe width="800" height="230" src=this.link></iframe>
                  
    </div>
  
</template>

<script>

import axios from "axios";

export default{
    
     name:"Camera",
     data(){
         return{
         link:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/08Xmfi1QIxc",
         
     };
     },
    methods:{
        
        OnSelectCam(link){
            this.link = link;
        },    
            
        },
   
}   
   
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <iframe width="800" height="230" :src="link"></iframe>
```

You need to add **:** before src and **""** to the variable name. You don't need this. inside the template.

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind your link value to the src attribute of your iframe
like this
`<iframe width="800" height="230" :src=this.link></iframe>`

Comment: It's been a while since i've used vuejs but you may be able to omit `this.` from `this.link`